# how to transfer data(array of mobile contacts) from one html page to other html using phonegap in android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have fetched data from device i.e all contacts from my mobile on device ready using ContactFindOptions() method. Now i want to send that array on new page contact.html. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Why you are fetching contacts in some other page if you need to transfer to another page ? You can fetch contact details in contact.html right ?

Comment: @vugneswaran no.. contacts are only fetched on device ready function i.e on index.html and it is my login page. I have fetced the contacts in index.html now i want them all to display on contacts.html page

Comment: Convert to JSON string and then save to localStorage. In contacts.html, retrieve from localStorage:  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to pass a data object from one html page top another, which I think is not feasible. To pass the arguments from one html page to another, you can use querystring methods.

Moreover, If you really need to pass the value of objects to another HTML, convert the data object to JSON string and pass it as an argument using QueryString.

for your reference: http://javascript.about.com/library/blqs.htm

Comment: @ankit..Thank you.. I have to pass a complete array which contains all the contact details of android device. so this is not the convenient way.. may be some other way

Comment: i understand your problem, and I think that you want to pass an object as an argument ro another html page. This is not currently supported by html per-se. You can only pass primitive data types as an argument. You should make calls to cordova and extract contact in contacts.html page. If the data-set is not large, just pass it as a json string argument to contacts.html page. Hope this helps.

Comment: or as suggested by @ezanker, you can put your data in some storage such as local/sqlite, and fetch it on contacts.html page. You could try 1 thing though. Include a .js in both the html. On the login html, fetch the contact and store it in a global variable, let's say connArray. Call the same js in contacts.html too and try to fetch the value of connArray. It might work, not sure though.

Comment: i tried to fetch the array created in index.js in contacts.html but it is nor returning any result. and as javascript doesn't trougn any error i m not getting where m goin wrong.

Comment: Phonegap is completely new for me.. and I am not even getting the proper tutorials to follow for the development. So if u know any please suggest. It wolud be very helpfull for me

Comment: Store the value of Array in a global variable in index.js file and try to fetch only the global variable in contacts.html. Yeah, debugging phonegap application is a big pain. Test you html and js on browser first. You can see the errors using console.log. In phonegap, try and put alerts to debug it. Moreover, which js framework are you using with pg?

Comment: I think that you can call deviceReady function anywhere in your code or in any js. Attach deviceReady function to contacts.html document, and make a call to the contacts api

Comment: deviceReady function is not called in any other js.

Comment: Once the device ready event has been called, "navigator" becomes available. You can call "navigator.contacts" in any html page within the application.

Comment: thank you ankit.. i did it.. n solved the issue.. thanks a lot for your help. and please do guide me for further work.. thanks a lot..

Comment: Great that you were able to resolve the issue. Do let me know if you need any help in future..have fun!